# GEKKO RTO vs MPC MODES

Tags: gekko

This is a question derived from this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60761440/variable-bounds-in-mpc-with-gekko). After posting my question I found a solution (more like a patch to force the optimizer to optimize). There is something that baffles me.  [John Hedengren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2366941/john-hedengren) correctly points out that a `b=1.0` in the ODE leads to an infeasible solution with `IMODE=6`. However in my patchy work around with `IMODE=3` I do get a solution.

I'm trying to understand what's happening here reading [GEKKO's](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/imode.html) documentation for `IMODE=3` and `6` but it is not clear to me

`IMODE=3`

> RTO Real-Time Optimization (RTO) is a steady-state mode that allows
>   decision variables (FV or MV types with STATUS=1) or additional
>   variables in excess of the number of equations. An objective function
>   guides the selection of the additional variables to select the optimal
>   feasible solution. RTO is the default mode for Gekko if
>   m.options.IMODE is not specified.

`IMODE=6`

> MPC Model Predictive Control (MPC) is implemented with IMODE=6 as a
>   simultaneous solution or with IMODE=9 as a sequential shooting method.

**Why b=1. works in one mode but not in the other?**

This is my patchy work around with `IMODE=3` and `b=1.0`:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0,23,24)

#initialize variables
T_e = [50.,50.,50.,50.,45.,45.,45.,60.,60.,63.,\
       64.,45.,45.,50.,52.,53.,53.,54.,54.,53.,52.,51.,50.,45.]
temp_low = [55.,55.,55.,55.,55.,55.,55.,68.,68.,68.,68.,55.,55.,68.,\
            68.,68.,68.,55.,55.,55.,55.,55.,55.,55.]
temp_upper = [75.,75.,75.,75.,75.,75.,75.,70.,70.,70.,70.,75.,75.,\
              70.,70.,70.,70.,75.,75.,75.,75.,75.,75.,75.]
TOU = [0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,200.,200.,\
       200.,200.,200.,200.,200.,200.,200.,200.,200.,\
       200.,200.,200.,0.05,0.05,0.05]

b = m.Param(value=1.)
k = m.Param(value=0.05)

u = [m.MV(0.,lb=0.,ub=1.) for i in range(24)]

# Controlled Variable
T = [m.SV(60.,lb=temp_low[i],ub=temp_upper[i]) for i in range(24)]

for i in range(24):
    u[i].STATUS = 1

for i in range(23):
    m.Equation( T[i+1]-T[i]-k*(T_e[i]-T[i])-b*u[i]==0.0 )

m.Obj(np.dot(TOU,u))

m.options.IMODE = 3
m.solve(debug=True)
myu =[u[0:][i][0] for i in range(24)]
print myu
myt =[T[0:][i][0] for i in range(24)]
plt.plot(myt)
plt.plot(temp_low)
plt.plot(temp_upper)
plt.show()
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(myu,color='b')
ax2.plot(TOU,color='k')
plt.show()
```

Results:

[image]

[image: Temperature]

[image: Input and Hourly cost]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the infeasible `IMODE=6` and the feasible `IMODE=3` is that the `IMODE=3` case allows the temperature initial condition to be adjusted by the optimizer. The optimizer recognizes that the initial condition can be changed and so it modifies it to 75 to both stay feasible and also minimize the future energy consumption.

[image: Feasible with hard constraints]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0,23,24)

#initialize variables
T_external = [50.,50.,50.,50.,45.,45.,45.,60.,60.,63.,\
              64.,45.,45.,50.,52.,53.,53.,54.,54.,\
              53.,52.,51.,50.,45.]
temp_low = [55.,55.,55.,55.,55.,55.,55.,68.,68.,68.,68.,\
            55.,55.,68.,68.,68.,68.,55.,55.,55.,55.,55.,55.,55.]
temp_upper = [75.,75.,75.,75.,75.,75.,75.,70.,70.,70.,70.,75.,\
              75.,70.,70.,70.,70.,75.,75.,75.,75.,75.,75.,75.]
TOU_v = [0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,200.,200.,200.,200.,\
         200.,200.,200.,200.,200.,200.,200.,200.,200.,200.,0.05,\
         0.05,0.05]

b = m.Param(value=1.)
k = m.Param(value=0.05)
T_e = m.Param(value=T_external)
TL = m.Param(value=temp_low)
TH = m.Param(value=temp_upper)
TOU = m.Param(value=TOU_v)

u = m.MV(lb=0, ub=1)
u.STATUS = 1  # allow optimizer to change

# Controlled Variable
T = m.SV(value=75)

m.Equations([T>=TL,T<=TH])
m.Equation(T.dt() == k*(T_e-T) + b*u)

m.Minimize(TOU*u)

m.options.IMODE = 6
m.solve(disp=True,debug=True)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,temp_low,'k--')
plt.plot(m.time,temp_upper,'k--')
plt.plot(m.time,T.value,'r-')
plt.ylabel('Temperature')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.step(m.time,u.value,'b:')
plt.ylabel('Heater')
plt.xlabel('Time (hr)')
plt.show()
```

If you went for another day (48 hours), you'd probably see that the problem would eventually be infeasible because the smaller heater `b=1` wouldn't be able to meet the temperature lower constraint.

One of the advantages of using `IMODE=6` is that you can write the differential equation instead of doing the discretization yourself. With `IMODE=3`, you use an Euler's method for the differential equation. The default discretization for `IMODE>=4` is `NODES=2`, equivalent to your Euler finite difference method. Setting `NODES=3-6` increases the accuracy with [orthogonal collocation on finite elements](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/OrthogonalCollocation).